# How do I determine the amount of time an object is in the air given these variables?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, projectile

An object is thrown straight up from 2 meters above the ground. Its apex is 8 meters. How long is its flight?

I don't understand how this question can be answered so if anyone can give me a detailed explanation I'd be very appreciative. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: what are the equations for position, velocity, and acceleration? How much is acceleration near the Earth's surface? Could you show us how far you've gotten on your own?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).